# How to get the records which are within the range when joining two tables

Tags: mysql

For a single table,I'm getting the records within the range using this query:

```
SELECT customerId,firstName,lastName FROM customer  WHERE customerId BETWEEN min AND max;
```

But after joining two tables,how can I get the records which are within the range.
Here, I'm using the foreignkey as below,

```
customer.productId = productDetails.productId
```

My Query :

```
SELECT customer.custId, customer.productId,GROUP_CONCAT(productDetails.productName) as productName, GROUP_CONCAT(productDetails.productPrice) as productPrice FROM customer, productDetails WHERE customer.productId = productDetails.productId  GROUP BY productDetails.productId
```

Comment: what is your result??

Comment: My result: custId |productId  | productName|productPrice|
 1000   |    371000 | watch,Book | 700,500    |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from what I understand you just need to add an "AND" condition to the query


WHERE customer.productId = productDetails.productId
AND customer.custId BETWEEN min and max; 
GROUP BY productDetails.productId
```